# Normalizing JSON with Pandas appends path to columns

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to parse a JSON file and export that into CSV that is going to be processed separately.

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
 "data": [
{
  "id": "fHF6fFQrZ8Qxwrw1ALiMC5_a2920fb2-e91b-11e9-9b3f-2fe890320230",
  "type": "leads",
  "attributes": {
    "facebook_url": "someurl",
    "status": "new",
    "twitter_handle": "somehandle",
    "first_visit_date": "2020-06-01",
    "last_visit_date": "2020-06-01",
    "linkedin_url": "linkedinlink",
    "name": "name",
    "website_url": "website",
    "industry": "Computer Software",
    "phone": "123123123",
    "crm_lead_id": null,
    "crm_organization_id": null,
    "employee_count": 10001,
    "tags": [],
    "logo_url": "logo"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "location": {
      "data": {
        "id": "a2920fb2-e91b-11e9-9b3f-2fe890320230",
        "type": "locations"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use pandas to normalize the data:

```
with open('leads.json') as data_file:
    d= json.load(data_file)

df = json_normalize(d['data'])
```

This results in the column names being named like this:

id  type    attributes.facebook_url attributes.status   attributes.twitter_handle attributes.first_visit_date

How am I supposed to get only the column names without the whole attribute path being attached to it?

edit: I will not parse the relationships node.

Example output would be:

`id  type    facebook_url
 1  sometype http://myurl`

Comment: json_normalize(d['data']['attributes']) ?

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data? Because attributes are for distinguish same values, like `id`, which exist in inner and output json parts

Comment: As said above, you'll get duplicated columns, add your target output and read [mcve]

Comment: added example output.

Comment: your JSON is not a valid json, also if you could provide an output that would cover the whole case that would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'])[['id', 'type', 'attributes.facebook_url']]
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('attributes.', '')
print(df)

                                                  id   type facebook_url
0  fHF6fFQrZ8Qxwrw1ALiMC5_a2920fb2-e91b-11e9-9b3f...  leads      someurl
```